# Getting a type error for API call and can't find the problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a list of ingredients in a useState array. When I handleSetIngredients with the setState function I get a type error when passing to the API at getRecipes.

Fridge.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Recipes from '../Recipes'
import recipeApi from '../../Api/Api'

function Fridge({setFavorites, favorites}) {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState([])
  const [searchedIngredients, setSearchedIngredients] = useState([])
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])

  //When input changes we will update the ingredient search query
  const handleChange = (e) => { 
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  //this will add an ingredient to the list we have in our fridge
  const handleSetIngredients = (e) => {
    setIngredientList( (prev) => [...prev, e.target.innerText])
  }

  //this will remove an ingredient in our list
  const handleRemoveIngredients = (e) => {
    setIngredientList( (prev) => prev.filter(ele => ele !== e.target.id))
  }

  //Here we will fetch for ingredients and set the searched ingredients to an array of objs
  const handleSearch = async (search) => {
    const quer = await recipeApi
      .searchForIngredients(search);
    setSearchedIngredients(quer)
  }

  //then we fetch for recipes from our ingreidents when our list changes
  const getRecipes = async (ingredientList) => {
    const quer = await recipeApi.getByIngredients(ingredientList);
    setRecipes(quer)
  }
  
  //call handle search when search changes; this will update fetch ingredients
  useEffect( () => {
    if(search){
    handleSearch(search)
  }
  }, [search])

  //this will fetch recipes when ingredient list changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if(ingredientList.length > 0)
    {
      getRecipes(ingredientList);
    }
  }, [ingredientList]);

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-900 w-screen flex flex-col lg:flex-row md:flex-row">
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full [&>*]:mt-10 [&>*]:ml-auto [&>*]:mr-auto mt-28">
        <p className="text-5xl font-semibold text-slate-200">
          What's in your fridge?
        </p>
        <form className="flex relative w-fit h-fit">
          <input
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Search ingredient"
            className="border-2 text-white bg-slate-800 w-[197px] h-[38px] p-1.5 rounded-3xl border-gray-900"
          />
          {
            <ul className="absolute top-[100%] w-full p-1 ">
              {searchedIngredients.length > 0 &&
                searchedIngredients.map((ele) => {
                  if (ele.name) {
                    return (
                      <button
                        key={ele.name}
                        onClick={handleSetIngredients}
                        className="bg-white border-b-2 m-auto first:rounded-t-lg last:rounded-b-lg w-full"
                      >
                        {ele.name}
                      </button>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div className="bg-white border-b-2 m-auto first:rounded-t-lg last:rounded-b-lg w-full">
                        No results...
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })}
            </ul>
          }
        </form>
        <div className="bg-slate-700 w-[40%] text-white p-5">
          <p className="ml-auto mr-auto w-fit pb-2">Ingredient List</p>
          <div>
            {ingredientList?.map((ing, i) => {
              return (
                <li
                  className="flex justify-between group border-t-[1px] border-slate-500 p-[3px]"
                  key={i}
                >
                  {ing}
                  <button
                    id={ing}
                    onClick={handleRemoveIngredients}
                    className="text-red-400 hidden group-hover:block"
                  >
                    X
                  </button>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {ingredientList.length > 0 && (
        <Recipes
          recipes={recipes}
          setFavorites={setFavorites}
          favorites={favorites}
          className="border-l-4 border-slate-600 w-full mt-28 flex flex-col [&>*]:ml-auto [&>*]:mr-auto"
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Fridge
```

Api.js

```
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": process.env.REACT_APP_HOST_URL
  },
};

const recipeApi = {
  getRandom: async () => {
    return await fetch(
      "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/random?number=1",
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => response.recipes)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  },

  getByIngredients: async (ingredientList) => {
    const querySearchIngredients = ingredientList.join().split(" ").join("");
     return await fetch(
      `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=${querySearchIngredients}&number=5&ranking=1`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => response)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  },

  getById: async (ids) => {
    const queryIds = ids.join("%2C%20").split(" ").join("");
    return await fetch(
      `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/informationBulk?ids=${queryIds}`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => response)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  },

  searchForIngredients: async (search) => {
    return await fetch(
      `https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/food/ingredients/autocomplete?query=${search}&number=10`,
      options
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => response)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  },
};

export default recipeApi;
```

I tried setting the initial value to something other than an empty array and it works. So somewhere in the process of changing the state of ingredientList is somehow changing the type.

Error

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Object.getByIngredients (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31:18)
    at getRecipes (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1571:73)
    at :3000/static/js/bundle.js:1585:7
    at commitHookEffectListMount (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32214:30)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33707:17)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33679:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33669:11)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33659:7)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35544:7)
    at flushPassiveEffects (:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35496:18)
```

Comment: Well what **exactly** is the error?

Comment: Its a type error. I just added it to post

Comment: Since you have multiple `fetch`es, you need to pinpoint which of them is failing. Try adding a random string to each of your `.catch((err) => console.error(err));`. For example, for the first one, it might be `.catch((err) => console.error("01 " + err));`, for the second `If you're unsure where the error is originating, try adding a random string to each of your `.catch((err) => console.error(err));`. For example, for the first one, it might be `.catch((err) => console.error("02 " + err));``. This will help you find which of the `fetch`es is causing the error.